# Ionic Laravel API PUT issue

Tags: angularjs, laravel, xmlhttprequest

I am struggling with the following request:

```
var spice = $http.put("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/Spices/", sanitizeSpice(spice, id));
```

where sanitizeSpice returns something like {amount: "54", id: "2")

I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/api/v1/Spices/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have the following filters set within Laravel (as shown in other examples I found here):

```
App::before(function($request)
{
  if (Request::getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
      $headers = array(
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'X-Requested-With, content-type',);
      return Response::make('', 200, $headers);
  }
});


App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST,GET,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS');
});
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't get the error with POST, GET, or DELETE. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you google **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**, the first hit is https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

You need to allow ajax calls in your nginx or apache2 config.

Use google to find good configurations for both of them.
E.g. for nginx:

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
```

Comment: I have Googled it several times. Have allowed for ajax calls. Still giving error.

Comment: Where did you put the add_header line? Try posting yoru entire nginx/apache2 config.